# How to display the image after rotation in gnu octave?

Tags: image, octave

```
I = imread("C:/Users/Hp/Desktop/download.jpg");
J = imrotate(I,90,nearest);
image(J);
```

This is the code i am using to rotate the image. The code doesn't give any errors but it isn;t displaying the rotated image.
Help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a bug. Try:

```
J = imrotate( I, 90, 'nearest' );
```

instead of

```
J = imrotate( I, 90, nearest );
```

The first uses the string 'nearest' as an option. The latter expects `nearest` to be an existing variable.

**UPDATE:**

Here's a fully worked example (image url from the web).

```
pkg load image
I = imread('https://i.imgur.com/I7GUK.jpg');
J = imrotate( I, -90, 'nearest' );
subplot( 1, 2, 1 ); image( I ); axis square off;
subplot( 1, 2, 2 ); image( J ); axis square off;
```

[image]

Comment: i made the change. but where do i see the rotated image?

Comment: Could you please explain the commands used to display the image?

Comment: @Chaitra the `image` function displays a matrix as an image. (is this what you're asking?)